# Finding unequal associated values

Tags: sql

```
+------+------+
| ColA | ColB |
+------+------+
| dog  |   74 |
| dog  |   74 |
| dog  |   74 |
| cat  |   55 |
| cat  |   55 |
| cat  |   55 |
| bird |   44 |
| bird |   43 |
| bird |   44 |
+------+------+
```

In the above table.

- All values (74) are the same, and are associated to "dog".
- The same applies to "cat", all values (55), are the same, and are associated to "cat".
- However with "bird", notice that not all values are the same, since there's a 44 and a 43 associated to "bird".

So how can I write out my SQL query, to return all animals, whose associated values aren't all the same, which would be "bird" in this case.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can do `GROUP BY` twice, and filter in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT g.ColA
FROM (
    SELECT a.ColA, a.ColB
    FROM Animals a
    GROUP BY a.ColA, a.ColB
) g
GROUP BY g.ColA
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Inner `GROUP BY` will produce one row for each distinct `{ColA;ColB}` pair; the outer `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` will reject `ColA`s with a single associated `ColB`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`, but no subquery is necessary:

```
select colA
from t
group by colA
having min(colB) <> max(colB);
```

This simply returns the `colA` values whose min and max `colB` values are different.

Answer (score 0):

```
select colA
from t
group by colA
having count(distinct colB) <> 1;
```

Similar to Gordon's but possibly a little more obvious what the purpose is.